# How to set a DatePicker's value dynamically?

Tags: c#, datepicker

I have an object datePicker in my form to show the birth date. I read the birth date from my DB (the date is a String in the format 'yyyyMMdd') I try to set the date read in the datePicker with the following code, but I get an exception. What did I do wrong ?!?

```
birth.Value= new DateTime(extractDate(r["H1DTN0"].ToString())); 


public long extractDate(String s)
    {
        String y = "";
        String m = "";
        String d = "";
        if(s.Length==8)
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach(char c in s)
            {
                if (index <= 3) y += c;
                else if (index >3 && index <= 5) m += c;
                else if (index >5) d += c;
                index++;
            }
            String data = y + m + d;
            long l = 0;
            long.TryParse(data,out l);

            return l;
        }
        else
        {

            return 0;


        }



    }
```

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: Dates do not have a format, so banish that notion.  Set the .Value property of the DateTimePicker to a valid `DateTime` value and Profit!

Comment: What exception?

Comment: @Zer0 it says that value is not  included between minValue and MaxValue,, which instead it is

Comment: You have a very distorted and incorrect notion of what `DateTime` is.  Suggested reading **[DateTime Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8)**

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp why? What I wanna do is simply to set the date I retrive from DB on the date picker

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution:

```
DateTime dtbIRTH = DateTime.ParseExact(extractDate(r["H1DTN0"].ToString()), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    birth.Value= dtbIRTH;
```

Using DateTime.ParseExact and specifying the date format it works perfectly.